# Why does Kali Linux not have ssh2john?

Tags: kali-linux

I tried to decrypt an SSH key, but didn't find `ssh2john` in Kali Linux. I had downloaded the latest version of Kali and John the Ripper is already pre-installed in it. I used the `locate *2john` command and can find other John tools, but not `ssh2john`. Why is this so? If I can't use `ssh2john`, are there any other tools or methods to replace it to crack the SSH key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research, I found that ssh2john not in JTR/src, it's in run:ssh2john.py. So I copy the py file to OS,then use python ssh2john.py id_rsa>idcrack to run. It succeed.
Then you can use john idcrack to crack the private key.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

in Kali you 'll find it there

```
/usr/share/john/ssh2john.py
```